# jQuery Full Calendar UnblockUI

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I sucessfully block the UI while events are loading.  I try to un-block the UI when all events are rendered with no luck..  Is there a better place to call Unblock?

```
    function getCalendar() {
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        loading: function (bool) {

            $.blockUI();
        },
    eventAfterAllRender: function(view)
        {
            $.unblockUI();
        },
     });
```

Comment: the **[loading](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/loading/)** callback has 2 parameters, first is **isLoading** - triggered with **true** when events are being fetched and **false** when done. Try something like loading: function (isLoading, view) { if(isLoading) { $.blockUI(); } else { $.unblockUI(); } }

Comment: Worked perfect.  Thanks smcd.